# How can I convert a raw pixel buffer (1D array) into a 2D array?

Tags: pixel, frame-buffer, rust

I have to deal with a raw buffer representing some pixels, specifically the [pixels crate](https://github.com/parasyte/pixels/). So far I am able to do some magic from the examples, however it is terribly bad when it comes to readability and I would like to convert that buffer into a 2D array, in order to access it more efficiently and make it easier for collision detection. So in order to draw a single pixel in position (512, 423), I want to do this:

```rust
fn draw_something(&mut self) -> /* ... */ {
    self.pixel_array_but_2d[512][423] = /* Some color in hex */;
}
```

I know I can also do this with other ways without the conversion to a 2D array, but I still want to do with the way I described.

Comment: [Are the answers here of any use to you?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72964366/3064164) When you say "convert", do you actually want to port the data from one container type to the other, or are you looking for a way to interface into the 1D data "as though" it were 2D?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by container. For the rest of the comment, 1. I will try to see if they help although the library is a bit more complex, 2. I just want to do `buffer[x][y] = 0xff;` instead of `buffer[y * width + x] = 0xff;` (Or whatever the formula is, like I said, the library examples are a bit confusing).

Comment: @AggelosT one possibility that doesn't require any additional allocation or indirection would be to wrap the pixel buffer access in a function, eg
```
fn draw_something(&mut self) -> /* ... */ {
    self.set_pixel(512, 423, /* Some color in hex */);
}

fn set_pixel(&mut self, x, y, value) -> /* ... */ {
    self.buffer[y * width + x] = value
}

fn get_pixel(&self, x, y) -> /* ... */ {
    self.buffer[y * width + x]
}
```